Long running waits- how to check/prove if the root case is at the SQL Side
Some of my users complain about the poor performance of the application developed/supported by an external company. The app uses SQL Server 2019 Enterprise Edition for a database engine.
I can see in our monitoring tool (Sentry) plenty of long-running blocking events and the days when users are complaining, thus I am almost sure that locking is a bottleneck they are facing.
Unfortunately, the monitoring tool catches the last query sent by a blocker, not a query that locked a table, and that last one seems to be  'irrelevant'.
I was able to catch an occurrence of that problem live with sp_whoisactive and a session that was blocking other users was holding locks (X on 'KEY' on different indexes, with request count between 1 and 80)  and it was in a 'sleeping' state for a couple of minutes. The last query in a batch was read-only (and I re-run it on dev, no X locks were raised there).
So, my hypothesis is that

App opens transaction
App update/insert/delete some rows which raises locks
The app sends read-only queries that I can see
There is some long-running processing on the app side
The transaction is committed/rollbacked after a couple of minutes

Thus my understanding is that speeding up SQL will not solve a problem as the root cause is at point 5 (or the whole design of a process).  While the vendor is laser focused on verifying SQL performance (index fragmentation, odd settings etc.) and the issue is open since quite a long time.
I am looking for a way to prove (or verify that I am wrong) that a bottleneck is somewhere else and the blocking session is indeed doing nothing and waiting for something outside of SQL.

Can you repro this in a test environment? I.e. playback a workload on non-production data.
If so, you can set the db to Read Comitted Snapshot Isolation and see if the problem goes away. That would imo be proof that app is waiting for locks, hence the problem is on the app side.
